# How to get all the rows from a table using Hibernate efficiently?

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans

I want all the rows from a table using hibernate to display. I used Hibernate 5.

I tried something like this 
But the method createCriteria showing as the depreciated method. Please suggest me an efficient way to get all the data from the table

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class).list();
```

I had a Student Bean class like this:

```
package com.Hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

and had a Student.hbm.xml file like :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 4 Jun, 2019 3:36:17 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.5.0.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.Hibernate.Student" table="STUDENT">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` interfaces in Hibernate 5+

```
// Create CriteriaBuilder
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Create CriteriaQuery
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = builder.createQuery(Student.class);

// Set root
Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);
criteria.select(root);

// Query execution
Query<Item> query = session.createQuery(criteria);
List<Item> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Can you please mention that what is the import for Query<Item>

Comment: import org.hibernate.Query;

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is works as expected